# ArcGIS IOS not displaying all layers of a TPK file

Tags: arcgis-engine, ios

I have an ArcGIS tpk file with 12 layers in it (Created a Tile package with 12 levels of detail). I used the tpk file as a local tiled layer and added it to my mapView but when i debug it, it seems that there were only 8 layers loaded in the tiled layer.

Is there a reason why it was only able to load 8 layers? Do i have to configure something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you step up the right visible Scale range for each layer in ArcMap?[image]